# How can i get and insert formatted text from mysql database and use it

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a news feed for my website. Right now the news column is of type `longtext`. I've `varchar` but it didn't work as well. There are a few rows with formatted text. I mean they have "carriage return". I get data from the database in code behind and set them to sessions. In design page I've tried this:

```
<div>sessioncode.toString()</div> 
<div>sessioncode</div> 

<div class="panel-body">
<%:Session["HaberIcerik"]%>
</div>
```

Both ignored `\r` (carriage return). The `<a>` tag looks like a normal `<a>` string. In code behind I did this:

```
sessionvalue = sqldatas.rows[0]["newscontent"];
sessionvalue = sqldatas.rows[0]["newscontent"].toString();
Session["HaberIcerik"] = haber.Rows[0]["haberIcerik"];
```

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A web browser will convert and condense new-lines to a whitespace as mandated in the HTML specification which requires `<br />` be used to indicate a line break.

Either pre-process the string before rendering:

```
sessionvalue = Regex.Replace(input_string, @"\r\n?|\n", "<br />");
```

Or render as-is but within an element that has the `white-space: pre` CSS style.

Comment: i have a record that has <br /> tag, but it does not look like html code. looks like this: http://yorumla.info/haber/2